# Find a two term expansion of the following equation

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

I want to find a two term expansion of the form $x\sim x_0 + \epsilon^\alpha x_1 + \epsilon^\beta x_2 + \ldots$, with $\alpha < \beta < \ldots$, for small $\epsilon$, of each solution $x$ of the following equation:
$$
x^2 - 2x + (1 - \epsilon^2)^{25} = 0
$$
I've substituted $x\sim x_0 + \epsilon^\alpha x_1 + \epsilon^\beta x_2 + \ldots$ into the equation to arrive at:
$$
(x_0 + \epsilon^\alpha x_1 + \epsilon^\beta x_2 + \ldots)^2 -2(x_0 + \epsilon^\alpha x_1 + \epsilon^\beta x_2 + \ldots) + (1 - \epsilon^2)^{25} = 0
$$
Since I want to find a two term expansion for the equation I want to find $x_0, x_1$ and $\alpha$. I will try to do so by inspecting the terms in the above equation.

$\mathcal{O}(1)$: If I look at the $\mathcal{O}(1)$ terms I find that $x_0$ needs to be chosen such that it satisfies
$$
x_0^2 - 2x_0 + 1 = 0
$$
The $1$ in this equation comes from the fact that $(1 - \epsilon^2)^{25} = 1+ \text{terms involving $\epsilon$}$. Solving this equation gives that $x_0 = 1$. Also since the $(1 - \epsilon^2)^{25}$ involves a term that is of order $\epsilon^2$, I know that I need $\alpha = 2$ for balance.

$\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$: If I look at the $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$ terms I find that I need to choose $x_1$ such that it satisfies 
$$
2x_0x_1 - 2x_1 - 1 = 0
$$
Where the $-1$ comes from the fact that $(1 - \epsilon^2)^{25}$ expansion contains $-\epsilon^2$. Since $x_0 = 1$ this means that I need to find $x_1$ such that
$$
2x_1 - 2x_1 -1 = 0
$$
But this is not possible..

**Question:** How do I find a two term expansion for the given equation? What am I doing wrong in my approach?

**Edit:** As Maxim pointed out, I did not consider the possibility that $\alpha = 1$. If $\alpha = 1$ I get $2x_0x_1 - 2x_1 = 0$ which is fine since $x_0= 1$. If $\alpha = 1$ then $\beta = 2$ because I need a term to balance the $-\epsilon^2$ in $(1 - \epsilon^2)^{25}$. With $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = 2$ I get the following equation:
$$
2x_0x_2 -2x_2 + x_1 -1 = 0\Leftrightarrow x_1 = 1
$$
Since I now know $x_0$ and $x_1$ I think I have a two term asymptotic expansion that looks like this:
$$
x = 1 + \epsilon + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^3)
$$
I'm not sure that this expansion is the result that I want though since I know that the equation
$$
x^2 - 2x + (1 - \epsilon^2)^{25} = 0
$$
has two solutions. As $\epsilon$ goes to zero, the first solution approaches one from below while the second solution approaches one from above. It seems that the expansion that I found is only an approximation of the second solution. Is this correct?

Comment: You haven't considered the possibility $\alpha = 1$. Then the $\epsilon^1$ terms in $x^2$ and in $2 x$ cancel each other out.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're equating the terms. What you should get is
$$x = 1 + x_1 \epsilon + x_2 \epsilon^2 + O(\epsilon^3), \\
x^2 - 2 x + (1 - \epsilon^2)^{25} =
(x_1^2 - 25) \epsilon^2 + O(\epsilon^3).$$

Answer (score 1):

The solutions to this equation are given by the quadratic formula as
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{(-2)^2-4(1)(1-\epsilon^2)^{25}}}{2}=1\pm\sqrt{1-(1-\epsilon^2)^{25}}$$
Now
$$(1-\epsilon^2)^{25}=\sum_{k=0}^{25}\binom{25}{k}(-\epsilon^2)^k=1-25\epsilon^2+300\epsilon^4-...-\epsilon^{50}$$
So the roots are given by
$$x_{1,2}=1\pm\sqrt{1-(1-25\epsilon^2+300\epsilon^4-...-\epsilon^{50})}$$
$$=1\pm\sqrt{25\epsilon^2-300\epsilon^4+...+\epsilon^{50}}$$
$$=1\pm\epsilon\sqrt{25-300\epsilon^2+...+\epsilon^{48}}$$
Now for small $\epsilon$ we can ignore terms of $\epsilon^4$ and greater giving the following approximation
$$x_{1,2}\approx1\pm\epsilon\sqrt{25-300\epsilon^2}$$
$$=1\pm5\epsilon\sqrt{1-12\epsilon^2}$$
The binomial expansion of the latter term is given by
$$\sqrt{1-12\epsilon^2}=1+\Big(\frac12\Big)(-12\epsilon^2)+...=1-6\epsilon^2+...$$
$$\therefore x_{1,2}\approx1\pm5\epsilon(1-6\epsilon^2)=1\pm5\epsilon\mp30\epsilon^3$$